# How can I loop through each of the days of a given week in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, loops, date

I am defining monday and friday using the following:

```
@monday = Date.today.at_beginning_of_week

@friday = 5.days.since(@monday)
```

But I actually need, for any given day, to loop through Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday and take that date and put the output into a  column.

```
<th>Monday</th>
<th>Tuesday</th>
etcetera
```

A given row, for example, would be:

```
<tr><td>method_with_arg(monday)</td><td>method_with_arg(tuesday)</td><td>method_with_arg(wednesday)</td></tr>
```

This is where value is a method that takes args date.

What's the cleanest way to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
def dates_week(d)
  (d.beginning_of_week...d.beginning_of_week+5).map{|a|
    "<td>#{a.strftime('%F')}</td>"
  }.join
end

dates_week Date.today
#=> "<td>2010-05-17</td><td>2010-05-18</td><td>2010-05-19</td><td>2010-05-20</td><td>2010-05-21</td>"
```

Instead of `a.strftime` you can call any other method receiving Date and returning string, such as `mails_sent_on(a)` etc. You can also use `yield a` there to pass your date-dependent logic using block:

```
def dates_week(d)
  (d.beginning_of_week...d.beginning_of_week+5).map{|a|
    yield a
  }.join
end

dates_week(Date.today) { |d|
  "<td>#{mails_sent_on(d)}</td>"
}
```

or, keeping strings out of `dates_week` method:

```
def dates_week(d)
  (d.beginning_of_week...d.beginning_of_week+5).map{|a|
    yield a
  }
end

dates_week(Date.today) { |d|
  mails_sent_on(d)
}.join(', ')
```

or whatever form you need.

Comment: I need to pass the actual value of the date into another method to output values for the other rows, such as emails sent, calls made, contacts added, etcetera...how can I set the output to be a variable I can plug in as an argument?

Comment: In addition to my concerns about non-DRY-ness, I think you need a bracket around `d.beginning_of_week+5` (Been there, done that)

Comment: @Angela: I'm not sure I understand you. @Andrew: No need for parenthesis there, at least in Ruby 1.9. Tried your example as well, works the same with or without the parens.

Comment: I guess what I mean is I need to pass an actual date (I think) not a string into another method for each row of the table (for example, show all the emails sent on that day)....would the format be sent_emails(a)?

Answer (score 1):

I just use Plain Old Ruby Objects, but I think if you want to keep things DRY, you'd want to separate out the logic of weekdays from what you're using the weekdays for.

```
def dates_week(d)
  d.beginning_of_week...(d.beginning_of_week+5)
end

dates_week(Date.today).map {|a|
  "<td>#{a.strftime('%F')}</td>"
}.join
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd go even one step further than Andrew and have it take a block:

```
def dates_week(d, delim)
  "<tr>" + (d.beginning_of_week...(d.beginning_of_week+5)).map do |day|
    "<#{delim}> #{yield(day)} </#{delim}>"
  end.join + "</tr>"
end

dates_week(Date.today, "th") {|d| d.strftime("%A")} # => <tr><th>Monday</th><th>Tuesday</th>...
dates_week(Date.today, "td") {|d| some_function(d)} #first row
```

Comment: okay going to go with this -- but now I can't find all the emails sent on the passed-in argument because the emails use a date-timestamp.... :\

Comment: You should be able to find() them such that day < time < day + 1

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution I could think of would be:

```
first_day = Date.today.at_beginning_of_week
days = 7.times.map {|x| first_day + x.days }

days.each do |day|
     puts "<td>" + func(day) + "</td>"
end
```

That should do the trick

Comment: This seems simple...but all of that would need to take place in the view or it would be in the dates_week()

Comment: I would define a helper method.